# Let $Y$ be the number of fair coins you have to flip until you get two heads in a row. What is the probability of the event $Y \leq 5$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Let $Y$ be the number of fair coins you have to flip until you get two heads in a row. What is the probability of the event $Y \leq 5$?

not sure if I have to sum up the probabilities of 1 to 5 of two heads in a row, or just find the probability of two heads for Y = 5. If I were to sum them up then the probability is over 1.

Comment: How many possible combinations of $5$ coin flips are there?  How many of those combinations have at least two heads in a row?

Comment: If you want to sum up probabilities, you have to sum the probabilities of HH, and THH, and TTHH and HTHH, and xxxHH where xxx is TTT or HTT or THT.

Answer (score 1):

You should instead count the number of cases in $5$ trials that **fail**,
and compute the desired probability by using the complement.

> The failure cases can easily be counted using a tree diagram as $13$

> Thus $P(Y<=5) = \Large\frac{32-13}{32} =\Large\frac{19}{32}$